# if-condition not evaluating properly in Javascript

Tags: javascript, conditional-statements

I am trying to create a checkers game but else if-coditional is not evaluating properly as tryAgain().invalidDiag(); is always called:

```
else if(row1 + 1 != row2 || row1 - 1 != row2 && col1 + 1 != col2 || col1 - 1 != col2){
    tryAgain().invalidDiag();
    console.log(row1, col1, row2, col2)
  }
```

The conditional is supposed to check if the move made was diagonal and only one space. Why is the conditional not evaluating properly?

Here is the full code:

```
var board, player1, player2, position1, position2, gameOn = false;


var resetBoard = function () {

  board = [
    [' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht'],
    ['wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X '],
    [' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht', ' X ', 'wht'],
    [' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X '],
    [' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X ', ' X '],
    ['red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X '],
    [' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red'],
    ['red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ', 'red', ' X ']
  ];
  displayBoard();
}

var tryAgain = function(){

  return {
    pcolor : function() {
      position1 = prompt("chose a "+player1+" peice to move");
      position2 = prompt("Where would you like to move it?")
      attemptMove(getMove(position1,position2).startRow, getMove(position1,position2).startCol, getMove(position1,position2).endRow, getMove(position1,position2).endCol);
    },
    invalidX : function() {
      position2 = prompt("Can only move to open space, try again");
      attemptMove(getMove(position1,position2).startRow, getMove(position1,position2).startCol, getMove(position1,position2).endRow, getMove(position1,position2).endCol);
    },
    invalidDiag : function() {
      position2 = prompt("Can only move diagonally, try again");
      attemptMove(getMove(position1,position2).startRow, getMove(position1,position2).startCol, getMove(position1,position2).endRow, getMove(position1,position2).endCol);
    }
  }  
}

var attemptMove = function(row1, col1, row2, col2)
{
  if(board[row1][col1] != player1) {
    tryAgain().pcolor();
  }
  else if(board[row1][col1] != 'wht' && board[row1][col1] != 'red'){
    tryAgain().pcolor();
  }
  else if(board[row2][col2] != ' X '){
    tryAgain().invalidX();
  }
  else if(row1 + 1 != row2 || row1 - 1 != row2){
    tryAgain().invalidDiag();
    console.log(row1, col1, row2, col2)
  } 
  else 
  {
    makeMove(row1, col1, row2, col2);
  }
}

var makeMove = function(row1, col1, row2, col2) {

   var col=board[row1][col1]; 
   board[row1][col1]=" X "; 
   board[row2][col2]=col;

   displayBoard();
}

var removePiece = function(row, col) {

}
//test calls her


var play = function(){
  gameOn = true;
  resetBoard();

  player1 = prompt("what color player would you like you be")
  position1 = prompt("what peice would you like to move?");
  position2 = prompt("where would you like to move it?");

  player1 = player1 === 'red' ? 'red' : 'wht';
  player2 = player1 === 'red' ? 'wht' : 'red';

  attemptMove(getMove(position1,position2).startRow, getMove(position1,position2).startCol, getMove(position1,position2).endRow, getMove(position1,position2).endCol);
}

var getMove = function(sMove, eMove){
  var startMove = sMove.split('');
  var endMove = eMove.split('');

  return {
    startRow : charToNum[startMove[0]],
    startCol : parseInt(startMove[1]),
    endRow : charToNum[endMove[0]],
    endCol : parseInt(endMove[1]),
    quit : true
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

- `A || B && C || D` evaluates like `A || (B && C) || D`. This is weird in your case.
- Worse, you are trying to see if `row2` is different from `row1 + 1` or `row1 - 1`. If `row2` is `row1 + 1`, then it is different from `row1 - 1`; whatever `row2` is, it will be different from at least one of them, if not both. You want to test for the situation where the position is *not bad*:

  ```
  if (!(row1 + 1 != row2 && row1 - 1 != row2 || col1 + 1 != col2 && col1 - 1 != col2))
  ```

  You can transform it by De Morgan's law and get this:

  ```
  if ((row1 + 1 == row2 || row2 - 1 == row2) && (col1 + 1 == col2 || col1 - 1 == col2))
  ```

  which is rather similar to what you had. Did you switch the meanings of `||` and `&&`, by any chance?

EDIT: Based on new requirements:

```
if ((player1 == "wht" ? row1 + 1 == row2 : row2 - 1 == row2) && (col1 + 1 == col2 || col1 - 1 == col2))
```

You might have to use "red" instead of "wht" :p

Comment: Or `(row1 + 1 == row2 || row1 - 1 == row2) && (col1 + 1 == col2 || col1 - 1 == col2)`, which might be slightly easier to understand.

Comment: @minitech: Yup! I type slowly... :p

Comment: (row1 + 1 == row2 || row1 - 1 == row2) && (col1 + 1 == col2 || col1 - 1 == col2) will still allow for a move forward and backward. The idea with this conditional is to only allow diagonal movement that is forward. So, if you are a red player you can only move up the board and if you are a wht player you can only move down.

Comment: @rahul2001: And you wrote this where? Your original post just says "diagonal and only one space". Anyway, check the update.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, to give proper precedence

```
else if((row1 + 1 != row2 || row1 - 1 != row2) && (col1 + 1 != col2 || col1 - 1 != col2)){
```

Comment: Also note that `(row1 + 1 != row2 || row1 - 1 != row2)` is always `true`.

Comment: minitech is correct -- it will not throw an error as it is always true

Answer (score 0):

Try to place some additional parentheses to make sure that the conditional is not short-circuited prematurely:

`else if((row1 + 1 != row2 || row1 - 1 != row2) && (col1 + 1 != col2 || col1 - 1 != col2)){`